# Segmentation fault in Gruff prevents me from generating a simple chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, gruff

I am experimenting with simple projects and RonR, specifically trying to generate some graphs using the gruff gem with rmagick and image magic. Everything is installed successfully, but when I run even a simple .rb with a chart it gives me the:

> > C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.4/lib/gruff/base.rb:467: [BUG] Segmentation fault
> >     ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]
> >
> > This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
> >     Please contact the application's support team for more information.

The line in the *base.rb* file is referring to this piece of code:

```
# Writes the graph to a file. Defaults to 'graph.png'
#
# Example:
#   write('graphs/my_pretty_graph.png')
def write(filename="graph.png")
   draw()
   @base_image.write(filename)
end
```

At the same time, the simple graph I am trying to draws seems simple enough, and it is from an example from Gruff's website:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'gruff'
g = Gruff::Bar.new('800x500') # Define a custom size
g.sort = false  # Do NOT sort data based on values
g.maximum_value = 50  # Declare a max value for the Y axis
g.minimum_value = 0   # Declare a min value for the Y axis
g.theme_37signals  # Declare a theme from the presets available

g.title = 'A more advanced bar chart'

g.data('Foo', [5, 10, 24])
g.data('Bar', [15, 3, 10])
g.data('Else', [38, 15, 32])

g.labels = {0 => 'Last year', 1 => 'This year', 2 => 'Next year'} # Define labels for each of the "columns" in data

g.write('a_more_advanced_graph.png')
```

I either try to load the above .rb script in *irb*, or directly load it in a controller. Both ways fail.

Even if try to do a graph in the controller and then show it in the view, it fails again. Every time the same segmentation error.

Just to note, I have the gems installed, as well added in Gemfile (if trying to do it from withing an app). I am running Rails on Windows and *gruff* is version *0.3.4*, although I also tried with latest version *0.3.6* but the same problem there as well.

Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably NOT related to your code,  but I can't be positive.

Analyze the error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.4/lib/gruff/base.rb:467:
   [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]
```

That says that while the gruff gem was executing,  when it hit line 467 in the base.rb file,  ruby threw a segmentation fault (a very LOW level error,  usually an attempt to access a memory location that doesn't exist)

So don't focus on your code,  focus on versions (i.e. version of ruby required, or version of gems that gruff depends on, etc.)

Comment: I still could not resolve the problem under windows, so I turned to the mighty linux :) As you can expect everything went fine there. So the problem was not in my code indeed, but most possibly a dependency with Image Magic and RMagick, resulting in gruff to interrupt IRB.